# Return raw html with node (just html into a var)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I'm trying to use jade via node, but when I run this code I get the html parsed by jade beetwen 'pre' tags.

```
var http = require('http');
var jade = require('jade');

http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

    response.end(jade.renderFile('index.jade'));
}).listen(8124);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

How can I make node render raw html without scaping anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render HTML, you need to use `'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'`. Using `text/plain` will render the HTML as plain text (without interpretation) and will make it look as if the HTML was rendered between `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: Thanks, I just copied that line from the docs and 'didn't read lol'

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us :).